# Jquery - adding image to multiple spans inside a table, dynamically created using Java

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I'm creating a table in Java class (in controlTableInitial() method):

```
res.add("<tr>"+"<td>"+result.getString("product_barcode")+"</td>"
+"<td>"+showed+"</td>"
+"<td>"+result.getString("product_price")+"</td>"
+"<td>"+result.getString("submit_user_email")+"</td>"
+"<td>"+result.getString("sales_date")+"</td>"
+"<td id='setSale'><span id='img'></span></td>"
+"</tr>"+"<br/>");
```

than, I build this table in .jsp file:

```
<%  
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    ControlPanel tbl = new ControlPanel();
    res = tbl.controlTableInitial();

%>
<table id="table">      
        <%
            for(int i=0;i<res.size();i++) {out.println(res.get(i));}
        %>
    </table>
```

And finally, I add image into span with id "img" using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#img").append('<img class="image" src="img/v.jpg"/>');
});
```

The problem is that i can see that image only in the 1st row, but not in others.
Also, using css, I change cursor type when hovering over the inserted image. And I can see cursor type changes in ALL rows where images should be (but, as I said, I can see iserted image only in the 1st row.).

Comment: You select the span with an id. Basically, 'id' supposed to identify single element in an html. Use the 'class' attribute instead.

Comment: You are right. I've changed `id` to `class` and it worked. Thank you.